# I3D3XFont::DrawTextW - Expanding tabs wrong?

Tags: c++, directx, tabbing, drawtext

I'm wondering if it's an issue with `I3D3XFont::DrawTextW`, I pass it a string with `\t` in it, which it expands. However, it doesn't always do it correctly. If I print the same string that I pass to it, the tabs are expanded correctly. For example,

```
dxfont->DrawTextW(NULL, msg, wcslen(msg), &textbox,
        DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_EXPANDTABS, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 180, 180, 180));
```

Where msg is created via:

```
swprintf_s(temp, sizeof(temp), L"%s\t\t\t\t%i\t\t%i\t\t%s\t\t%i\n",
        pList[x].name.c_str(), pList[x].kills, pList[x].deaths, wratio,
        pList[x].suicides);
```

Which, when printed to console comes out as:

```
Bamrow<4x tab>0<2x tab>0<2x tab>N/A<2x tab>2
```

But, DrawTextW displays it as

```
Bamrow<5x tab>0<2x tab>0<2x tab>N/A<2x tab>2
```

Has anyone else had this issue and/or knows a solution?

Comment: That's a really strange transformation.  Is it possible your capturing for analysis is munging the text?

Comment: I don't think so. I have a row of text above that (for DrawText) which is spaced to 4 tabs correctly, and the output from this DrawText shows the data after the name one tab too far. I included <4x tab> etc because when I inserted a tab character it didn't show anything when posting the message.

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit. I have two possible swprintf_s statements, shown below. 

if (len >= 8)
swprintf_s(temp, sizeof(temp), L"%s\t\t\t%i\t\t%i\t\t%s\t\t%i\n", pList[x].name.c_str(), pList[x].kills, pList[x].deaths, wratio, pList[x].suicides);
else
swprintf_s(temp, sizeof(temp), L"%s\t\t\t\t%i\t\t%i\t\t%s\t\t%i\n", pList[x].name.c_str(), pList[x].kills, pList[x].deaths, wratio, pList[x].suicides);

While this works for many names, if the person's name is comprised of capital letters, ie MEMEME, it will be spaced too far, whereas mememe would be spaced correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, sorry. Fixed it. I needed to ratio the tabs based on the pixel length of the word, not how many characters there are. GetTextExtent32W did the trick.